# STS+Roo basics: Custom Method

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-roo

i generate a Roo-project from Database and try to get some Experiences in using roo.

id like to send an eMail when i just save a new "user", so i go into the

```
UserController_roo_Controller.aj
```

and modify the aspect's create-method. Unfortually roo overwrite this roo-controller sometimes.

i guess this is the wrong class iv edited. so where do i place that functionallity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you editing the aj file or the java file?  Roo will replace methods in an AspectJ (aj) file but not the java file.

If this is the case move the create method into from the aj class to the java class and Roo will stop auotmaticlly generating the method

Comment: ah, ok. but how will the aj call my method?

Comment: The aj class are merged (woven) with the java class at compile time to produce the final compiled jar. There is some background [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_weaver).  If you were to decompile your jar file you would find that it contained all the methods from both the java and aj classes, AspectJ will will not overwrite a method in a class with one from an aspect (aj)